# Python google drive API download, where is file?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I used the python code found here to download a file on google drive:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads
I have this scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
everything seems to work, I read:

```
Download 35%.
Download 71%.
Download 100%.
```

but where is the file? in the same directory as the python file, there is nothing, neither the root, nor in the home ... you have ideas? or alternatively how can I debug?

Comment: probably it is in memory - in `fh` (`fh = io.BytesIO()`). You have to save it using `open(..., 'wb')`, `write(fh)`, `close()`.

Comment: With your hint I did a search with different keywords and found the problem, just replace fh = io.BytesIO()
with: fh = io.FileIO(filename, 'wb')
thank you

Comment: Is there a way to use the file without saving it locally?  Such that, if the file was an image, could I load fh in to a variable and display it?

Answer (score 12):

Example in Google doc uses

```
fh = io.BytesIO()
```

so it reads data into memory and it doesn't save on disk.

You have to save it using (for example)

```
my_file = open(filename, 'wb')
my_file.write(fh)
my_file.close()
```

---

**EDIT**: information for others - as @michelle.70 found - we can use

```
fh = io.FileIO(filename, 'wb')
```

instead of `fh = io.BytesIO()` and it will save it in file.

It should also work if you use normal `open()`

```
fh = open(filename, 'wb')
```

Don't forget to close `fh` (in both methods).