# NameError: name 'MediaIoBaseDownload' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

*Python 3.7.2*

```
$ pip3 list | grep googl
google-api-python-client 1.7.9    
google-auth              1.6.3    
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3    
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.0
```

I use [this example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) from Google Drive API reference to download files

```
def downloadFile(driveService, fileId):
    request = driveService.files().get_media(fileId=fileId)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

And I get error

```
$ python3 quickstart.py
Files:
mov_bbb.mp4 (1dAPxwZ24_ptTRe87eNG6kTAagIh-JUt0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart.py", line 61, in main
    downloadFile(service, item['id'])
  File "quickstart.py", line 16, in downloadFile
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
NameError: name 'MediaIoBaseDownload' is not defined
```

Where can get this `MediaIoBaseDownload`?

All the code I have

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
import io
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def downloadFile(driveService, fileId):
    request = driveService.files().get_media(fileId=fileId)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    #fh = io.FileIO(fileId + '.mp4', 'wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        q="mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
        pageSize=10,
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
    ).execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
            downloadFile(service, item['id'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can get the class from googleapiclient.http

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
```

Comment: Hi @srgbnd, could you supply the url from where you found that at?

Comment: Where are the downloaded file. I am unable to find them.

Comment: To download as an actual file, use `FileIO` instead of `BytesIO`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292375/python-google-drive-api-download-where-is-file